# How can I fix the black bar Viewport with higher resolution?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm starting to create a game using **libgdx**. I'm testing different viewports to see what is the best viewport for my game. However, when I tested my app using the *Android Studio* with the virtual device **6.71"(1440x3120)**, I got a black bar on the top of the screen.


 Here is the code that I'm using :

```
@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    img = new Texture("mainMenuBackground.png");
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new FillViewport(1920, 1080, camera);
    viewport.apply();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    camera.update();
    ScreenUtils.clear(1, 0, 0, 1);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
    img.dispose();
}
 
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height){
    viewport.update(width,height);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0);
}
```

Here is the result that I'm getting:

[image: Game view with the black bar]

I tried to remove the black bar using all the viewport but with no avail.